# What is the purpose of this secret in Azure Container App?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have encountered a secret created in my Azure Container App, but I don't find any references of this secret, who has created it, how it was created, where it come from, nor the microsoft explains about it.

This secret is created by default, once I have created the Azure Container App. It just appears there.

Please explain what is a purpose of this key,
[image]

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/691 <- I am still reading this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As mentioned in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/728) by @*mgelei*, when you create a container app with an external registry, it creates a secret automatically to store the token needed to log in.**

I have also observed the same when I test it in my environment: a default secret is getting created if we select any container registry to deploy during creation of container app.

- **Creating Container App by selecting the Image:**

[image]

- Secret got created automatically:

[image]

I have created a container app without selecting the container registry (Checked `use quickstart Image`) to deploy. I could see secret is not getting created.

- **Creating Container App with selecting the registry:**

[image]

- No secret got created automatically.

[image]